# App crashes while loading another activity in android development

Tags: java, android, android-activity, imagebutton

My app crashes while I try to load another activity through a Imagebutton.

Myfirstactivity

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    
    public void profile(View view)
    {
        Intent gender_intent = new Intent(this,genderselection.class);
        startActivity(gender_intent);
    }
}
```

MyfirstActivity xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background = "@drawable/original"
    >
   <ImageButton
        android:gravity = "center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop = "-345dp"
        android:id = "@+id/m_b"
        android:layout_width ="200dp"
        android:layout_height = "200dp"
        android:background= "@drawable/profile"
        android:onClick = "Profile"
   />
   <TextView
        android:layout_width ="200dp"
        android:layout_height = "50dp"
        android:text = "ENTER NAME"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:layout_below = "@id/m_b"
        android:textSize = "27dp"
        android:textColor = "#000000"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:id = "@+id/textname"
   />
   <EditText
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:layout_width ="200dp"
        android:layout_height = "50dp"
        android:layout_below = "@id/textname"
        android:id = "@+id/input"
   />
   <ImageButton
        android:gravity = "bottom"
        android:layout_width ="200dp"
        android:layout_height = "50dp"
        android:text = "Confirm"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff"
        android:background = "@drawable/done"
        android:layout_marginBottom= "-100dp"
    />
        
    
    
        
        
        
</RelativeLayout
```

Mysecondactivity

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.Intent;

public class genderselection extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gender);
    }
}
```

MySecondActivity xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    
    <ImageButton
         
        android:gravity= "center_vertical"
        android:layout_height = "120dp"
        android:layout_width = "120dp"
        android:background = "@drawable/mprofile"
        />
    
</LinearLayout
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:resizeableActivity = "true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I m completely new and not using android studio.
It just a simple ide
Pls help me
Thanks

I m using ide of play store and doing this coding in my phone

Comment: Where are you loading the second activity with image ? all I see are 2 activities with 2nd activity having image which you are trying to load from ?

Comment: add error log also

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code, you do not add your second activity in manifest file. Try to update your manifest file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.myapp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:resizeableActivity = "true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".genderselection"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
       
    </activity>
    
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your Manifest File, I note that your activities have the same name set as **.MainActivity**.
You need to ***delete the below 2nd activity tag in your Manifest File***

```
`<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`
```

***And Replace the above code with this line*** for the Second Activity

```
<activity android:name=".genderselection"></activity>
```